# Outputted data shows each related record instead of one with no data in the last field

Tags: mysql

I'm outputting a list of cruises to show availability status, but I'm getting each cruise several times with each cabins status, I only want the cruise, then if all the cabins are sold out the outputted status should be C, otherwise A

here are my queries

```
<?php
$maketemp = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp (
                 `sailingId` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
                 marketCurrency varchar(3),
                 `Status` varchar(1)
             )";

mysql_query( $maketemp, $connection ) or
    die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error ( ) );

$inserttemp = "INSERT INTO
                   temp
               SELECT
                   code AS sailingId,
                   'USD' AS marketCurrency,
                   CASE
                       WHEN fares_usa.status = 'sold_out' THEN 'C'
                   END AS Status
               FROM
                   cruises,
                   fares_usa
               WHERE
                   live ='Y' AND
                   cruises.id = fares_usa.cruise_id";

mysql_query( $inserttemp, $connection ) or
    die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error ( ) );

$select = "SELECT sailingId, marketCurrency, Status FROM temp";

$export = mysql_query ( $select, $connection ) or
    die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );

$fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );
```

Comment: You don't provide enough information about tables `cruises` and `fares_usa` for anyone to give a reasonable answer. Also, stop using the mysql_* extension. It is obsolete and will eventually be deprecated. Use PDO instead.

Comment: what's PDO ? I'm using mysql_ cause that's what the tutorials I've read use./

Comment: Here is a tutorial explaining the whys and hows of using PDO. http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I did it...

```
 $inserttemp = "INSERT INTO temp SELECT code AS sailingId, 'USD' AS marketCurrency, CASE WHEN GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT status) = 'Sold Out' THEN 'C' ELSE 'A' END AS Status FROM cruises, fares_usa WHERE live ='Y' AND cruises.id = fares_usa.cruise_id GROUP BY cruises.code";
```

result !